# SWT Table Viewer key listener for default actions

Tags: java, swt, jface

How can I override the default key actions like ctrl+C, ctrl+A etc. on a table viewer ? Here is the key listener I added to my table. It works for custom key combinations, like ctrl+W, but not for the default ones.

```
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if( e.keyCode == 'a'
                    && ( e.stateMask & SWT.MODIFIER_MASK ) == SWT.CTRL ) {
                // do something
            }
        }
```

Comment: This works OK on macOS, possibly the native control on your platform is not passing on some standard key actions. Why do you want to handle these standard actions?

Comment: i'm trying to make certain rows un-selectable, so I want to redirect the ctrl+A action to only select the available rows.

Comment: @greg-449 do you think it has anything to do with the fact that on macOS the action combination for select all is cmd+A instead of ctrl+A ?

Comment: I get events for Cmd+A as well as Ctrl+A (using SWT.MOD1 modifier)

Comment: @greg-449 and you're adding a KeyListener to the Table Viewer's table right ? like this ?  viewer.getTable().addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {...}

Comment: Yes, I am using that listener. Also the same with the low level `SWT.KeyPress` listener.